# How to replace all \W (none letters) with exception of '-' (dash) with regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, string

I want replace all `\W` not letters with exception of `-` dash to spaces i.e:

1. `black-white` will give `black-white`
2. `black#white` will give `black white`

I know regular expression very well but I have no idea how to deal with it.

Consider that I want use Unicode so `[a-zA-Z]` is not `\w` like in English only.
Consider that I prefer Python re syntax but can read other suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using negated character class: (`\W` is equivalent to `[^\w]`; `[^-\w]` => `\W` except `-`)

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^-\w]', ' ', 'black-white')
'black-white'
>>> re.sub(r'[^-\w]', ' ', 'black#white')
'black white'
```

If you use [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package, you can use [nested sets, set operations](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex#nested-sets-and-set-operations):

```
>>> import regex
>>> print regex.sub(r'(?V1)[\W--[-]]', ' ', 'black-white')
black-white
>>> print regex.sub(r'(?V1)[\W--[-]]', ' ', 'black#white')
black white
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like below,

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?!-)\W', r' ', 'black-white')
'black-white'
>>> re.sub(r'(?!-)\W', r' ', 'black#white')
'black white'
```

`(?!-)\W` the negative lookahead at the start asserts that the character we are going to match would be any from the `\W` (non-word character list) but not of hyphen `-` . It's like a kind of substraction, that is `\W - character present inside the negative lookahead` (ie. hyphen).

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sS1qO8/2)

Comment: you could also use this `-(*SKIP)(*F)|\W` https://regex101.com/r/sS1qO8/3 but regex module fails to support this.

Comment: Nice idea to do better word splitting.